# aws kms Same ciphertext for same text

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kms

In AWS KMS, can we get the same ciphertext for the same input every time? I am trying to encrypt the user's password. I am planning to use the user's ID as the input text. If the user ID is the same, I need to receive the same ciphertext.

How do I achieve this using Python? Also, can that ciphertext be converted to a string?

Comment: Are you sure you want encryption and not hashing here?

Answer (score 0):

When you use KMS for encrypting data, there are several steps involved

1. You create your KMS key (via console, CloudFormation, API, etc). This is NOT the key that will encrypt your data. Instead, this is a `Master` key
2. Then, when you actually want to encrypt some data, KMS will generate a data key for you and encrypt this data key with master key. That data key is used for encryption of actual data. Different data keys can be generated by KMS each time you encrypt new piece of data.

Because of the above, you cannot guarantee that same encryption key is used when you encrypt something with KMS. Benefit of this approach, is that if someone gets hold of a single data encryption key they won't be able to decrypt other data, since they all have different data keys.

If you want to use same encryption key everytime you can just generate key yourself and store it in AWS Secrets Manager, for example.

I also wonder if hashing might be a better solution in your case (
for example, if you just want to be able to compare two user IDs).